How to use event.target.closest for navbar html javascript css?
I'm making a navbar. On click of items which has subnav pages, the navigation item/expands or collapses.
Here's the HTML/JS/CSS snippet.


const navHasChilds = document.getElementsByClassName("hasChild");
Array.from(navHasChilds).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.target.closest(".hasChild").querySelector(".subnav").classList.toggle('active');
  event.target.closest(".hasChild").querySelector(".collapsible").classList.toggle('collapsible-expanded');
}));
body { background: #999; }

.collapsible {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.collapsible-expanded {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.collapsible-expanded:after {
  content: '\2212';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

ul.subnav {
  display: none
}

ul.subnav.active {
  display: block;
}
<li class="hasChild"><a>System<i class="collapsible"> </i> </a>
  <ul class="subnav">
    <li><a onclick='EASauthorized("/setup.html")'>Setup</a></li>
    <li><a onclick='EASauthorized("/date.html")'>Date</a></li>
    <li><a onclick='EASauthorized("/languages.html")'>Languages</a></li>
    <li><a onclick='EASauthorized("/settings.html")'>Settings</a></li>
    <li><a onclick='EASauthorized("/mgmt.html")'>Management</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>



Right now, On click of items under class "subnav", the nav item expands/collapses. I want to retain expand/collapse state until the + or - icon is clicked and not on clicking every page link. (i.e) I want event listener working only for the main navigation menu and not the pages (subnav) under the navlink.
What's wrong here?

There are no + or - icons in the example you've provided. Can you please edit the question to include them

Too much color: white; in the example, on a default white background :-) I added a background color for body, so that the +/- icons are visible.

Please make your code reproducible

If you want only the +/- icons the expand/collapse the thing, then you can use const navHasChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".hasChild .collapsible"); to bind the click hander only to those icons in the first place. If clicking on "Setup" is also supposed to work as toggle, use const navHasChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".hasChild > a"); instead.

On using, navHasChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".hasChild > a"); Clicking "Setup" would also toggle the menu. But I want toggle only on clicking "System". Please check the edited code. I had used Setup in 2 places earlier

Just tested @CBroe's second suggestion (.hasChild > a) and it seems to be working as you wanted, only toggling the subnav when the parent is clicked. Added a second menu option + subnav section for testing, and it handled that fine too, though obviously it doesn't collapse a currently expanded section if another is clicked.

@l3l_aze I can see even listener in chrome debugger for  all the "a" tags under "hasChild" class. And so it collapses a currently expanded section if another is clicked
